# Execute C scripts using PHP

Tags: php, c

I need to run a c program in PHP to establish a socket connection and to retrieve a result back from the server.

I have written a C Program to establish a socket connection and server receives the request.

How to convert a C program into .dll file to use as a PHP extension?

Comment: Have you tried to use netcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using socket you can't run any c application directly .You need to call that executable to run .

My idea is you can run  another client application on remote and send some data to socket and in remote the client will receive the message based on which it can run he application.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
You can receive the file sent from client and save it to disk.
Then, you may use *system* to compile the file received.
The last step, you run it, use the *system* again.

But i am not suggest you do that, as it may be dangerous, you never know what the code does. It may deletes all your files in the disk. What's more, the libs the code depend on may not be installed.

**Method2:**
use the loadable library:
1. all the code sent to server is implement a generic interface
2. pre-compile the code to loadable library
2. server save the code to disk
3. server load the library and call the generic interface
More about loadable library, please check [it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) out.

Answer (score 0):

We can not run a C Program directly with PHP, Because to run a C script there is no compiler with any LAMPP, XAMPP, WAMP. If we need to run any C script, Create a PHP Extension with C code with ZEND Engine standards(Check the syntax to receive the parameters in C from PHP).

```
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ls|b", &intNumber, &strVal,  &return_long) == FAILURE) {
         RETURN_NULL();
    }
```

WINDOWS:

Refer this link to create a PHP Extension with C Scripts:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/244215-introduction-to-creating-a-php-extension-for-windows/
Move the extension file to /ext/ folder and add the extension name in php.ini file

LINUX:

http://linux.ferhatbingol.com/2013/06/06/how-to-create-php-extensions/
In a linux, by default .so file will move to  **/usr/lib/php5/** XXXXXXXX/extension.so
, Specify this extension path in your PHP.ini file

Then restart the apache server, finally our PHP Extension will work fine.